# How to groupby column using JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I have imported text file with following values name,age,qualification,sex,salary with multiple rows to `JavaRDD<String>`

How do i count number of male and female?

- Example
- Male 10
- Female 14

Should i get the column sex to another `JavaRDD<String>` or can i apply `JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>`
?
Without using dataframes

I have tried this

```
JavaRDD<String> getdata = sc.textfile("gettext.data");

JavaPairRdd<String,Integer> pairgroup = getdata.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {

@Override
public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String arg0) throws Exception {

        String[]  aRow= arg0.toString().split(",");
        String Sex = aRow[3];

    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(Sex, 1);
}
}).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

@Override
public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
    return v1 + v2;
}
}).foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {

@Override
public void call(Tuple2<String, Integer> t) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(t._1 + " " + t._2);

}
});
```

Comment: use filter on the RDD

Comment: Could u please elaborate. I am very new to Spark and I am just lost after  trying this for hours

Comment: use pairGroup.stream().filter().collect()    to get an RDDof just one gender. Google 'java RDD stream filter' for details.

Comment: (I work more in scala so I don't have the exact syntax in my head atm)